# messagebird messages are not being delivered

Tags: python, messagebird

```
    import messagebird

    ACCESS_KEY = ""
    client = messagebird.Client(ACCESS_KEY)
    message = client.message_create(
        'TestMessage',
        '+91XXXXXXXXX',
        'working',
        { 'otp' : 1234 }
    )
    print(client)
```

I am using above code to send message. But, I am not getting any message to my phone.

It is giving this in response.

```
 <messagebird.client.Client object at 0x100f6f280>
```

Check the screenshot.
From here i got the api key to test

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the test api key, this doesn't send a message it just validates that the api call was formatted properly.
it might be worthwhile using pprint to print the output.